# Pandas dataframe CSV reduce disk size

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, compression

For my university assignment, I have to produce a csv file with all the distances of the airports of the world... the problem is that my csv file weight 151Mb. I want to reduce it as much as i can: This is my csv:

[image]

and this is my code:

```py
# drop all features we don't need
for attribute in df:
    if attribute not in ('NAME', 'COUNTRY', 'IATA', 'LAT', 'LNG'):
        df = df.drop(attribute, axis=1)

# create a dictionary of airports, each airport has the following structure:
# IATA : (NAME, COUNTRY, LAT, LNG)
airport_dict = {}
for airport in df.itertuples():
    airport_dict[airport[3]] = (airport[1], airport[2], airport[4], airport[5])
    
# From tutorial 4 solution:
airportcodes=list(airport_dict)
airportdists=pd.DataFrame()
for i, airport_code1 in enumerate(airportcodes):
    airport1 = airport_dict[airport_code1]
    dists=[]
    for j, airport_code2 in enumerate(airportcodes):
        if j > i:
            airport2 = airport_dict[airport_code2]
            dists.append(distanceBetweenAirports(airport1[2],airport1[3],airport2[2],airport2[3]))
        else:
        # little edit: no need to calculate the distance twice, all duplicates are set to 0 distance
            dists.append(0)
    airportdists[i]=dists
airportdists.columns=airportcodes
airportdists.index=airportcodes

# set all 0 distance values to NaN
airportdists = airportdists.replace(0, np.nan)
airportdists.to_csv(r'../Project Data Files-20190322/distances.csv')
```

I also tried re-indexing it before saving:

```py
# remove all NaN values
airportdists = airportdists.stack().reset_index()
airportdists.columns = ['airport1','airport2','distance']
```

but the result is a dataframe with 3 columns and 17 million columns and a disk size of 419Mb... quite not an improvement...

Can you help me shrink the size of my csv? Thank you!

Comment: 17 000 000 rows * 3 columns / 1024 / 1024 = 48 Mb if assuming one char by row
151 Mb = average 3 chars by row ... how do you want to shrink your output file? not possible? except if you want multiples files smaller

Comment: Thank you @Frenchy yeah I'm not sure if it is possible to reduce the file dimension, that's what I'm asking eh eh

Comment: how many airports have you?

Comment: @Frenchy 9541 airports

Comment: Not significantly. 9541 airports means you have ~91 million airport pairs, 45.5 million if you ignore the duplicates. For most of those you need between 3-4 characters for the distance, and one for separator. That considered 151 MiB is pretty good. CSV being plain text isn't very space efficient. Unless you use compression and/or binary format, you won't do much better. | Why is it a problem anyway?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have done a similar application in the past; here's what I will do:

It is difficult to shrink your file, but if your application needs to have for example a distance between an airport from others, I suggest you to create 9541 files, each file will be the distance of an airport to others and its name will be name of airport.

In this case the loading of file is really fast.

Comment: I'll try this asap and I'll let you know ;-)

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion will be instead of storing as a CSV try to store in Key Value pair data structure like JSON. It will be very fast on retrieval. Or try parquet file format that will consume 1/4 of the CSV file storage.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pathlib import Path
from string import ascii_letters

#created a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10000,size=(1000000, 52)),columns=list(ascii_letters))

df.to_csv('csv_store.csv',index=False)
print('CSV Consumend {} MB'.format(Path('csv_store.csv').stat().st_size*0.000001))
#CSV Consumend 255.22423999999998 MB

df.to_parquet('parquate_store',index=False)
print('Parquet Consumed {} MB'.format(Path('parquate_store').stat().st_size*0.000001))
#Parquet Consumed 93.221154 MB
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, add some more description and code if it's required to understand the answer because it will resolve someone's else problem ASAP.

Answer (score 2):

The title of the question, "..reduce disk size" is solved by outputting a compressed version of the csv.

```
airportdists.to_csv(r'../Project Data Files-20190322/distances.csv', compression='zip')
```

Or one better with Pandas 0.24.0

```
airportdists.to_csv(r'../Project Data Files-20190322/distances.csv.zip')
```

You will find the csv is hugely compressed.

This of course does not solve for optimizing load and save time and does nothing for working memory. But hopefully useful when disk space is at a premium or cloud storage is being paid for.

Comment: Uhm, yeah I was actually looking for a solution that doesn't involve zip file: like with music mp3 or with images png, jpeg: I would like to avoid zipping the file but instead using a different compression algorithm to reduce it's space on disk

Comment: I don't fully understand. 0.24.0 has a variety of compression strategies. `zip` is just one.  So I think maybe you are hoping to reduce the amount of working memory while the data is loaded in pandas.  For that, it will be an algorithm/data structures problem to solve.

Answer (score 1):

The best compression would be to instead store the latitude and longitude of each airport, and then compute the distance between any two pairs on demand. Say, two 32-bit floating point values for each airport and the identifier, which would be about 110K bytes. Compressed by a factor of about 1300.

Comment: Hi Mark, can you be more specific? what is a compression factor?

Comment: Divide the number of uncompressed bits by the number of compressed bits.